# A method in python not working which is imported from other py file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python class which has to use a function in another python file. I imported the class and there in no import error but it gives an error  about attribute not present

My files re combact.py and monster.py. I have imported combat.

This is combact.py

```
import random

   class Combat():
       dodge_limit = 6
       attack_limit = 6

       def dodge(self):
          roll = random.randint(1,self.dodge_limit)
          return roll > 4

       def attack(self):
          roll = random.randint(1,self.attack_limit)
          return roll > 4
```

This is monster.py

```
 import random
from combact import Combat

COLOR = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']


class Monsters(Combat):
    max_hitpoints = 1
    min_hitpoints = 1
    max_experience = 1
    min_experience = 1
    weapon='sword'
    sound = 'roar'
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.hit_points = random.randint(self.min_hitpoints,self.max_hitpoints)
        self.color = random.choice(COLOR)
        self.experience = random.randint(self.min_experience,self.max_experience)

        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} HP: {} XP: {}'.format(self.color.title(),self.__class__.__name__,self.hit_points,self.experience)


    def battlecry(self):
        return self.sound.upper()


class Goblin(Monsters):
    max_experience=2
    min_hitpoints = 2
    max_hitpoints = 3

    sound = 'Squek'

class Troll(Monsters):
    max_experience = 5
    min_experience = 2
    max_hitpoints = 8
    min_hitpoints = 5

    sound = 'Wiggling'

class Dragon(Monsters):
    max_hitpoints = 10
    min_hitpoints = 7
    max_experience = 10
    min_experience = 8

    weapon = 'fire'
    sound = 'raaaaaaar'
```

When I run monsters.py Output is:

[image: When I run monsters.py Output is:]

This is another file character.py with same import but its Working
[image]

If You Need character.py

```
 from combact import Combat

class Character(Combat):
    experience  = 0
    hit_points = 10

    def get_weapon(self):
        wep = input("Choose Your Weapon.([S]word , [A]xe , [B]ow)").lower()

        if wep in 'sab':
            if wep == 's':
                return 'sword'
            elif wep == 'a':
                return 'axe'
            else:
                return 'Bow'

        else:
            print("Weapon not in you arsenal right now")
            return self.get_weapon()



    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.name = input("Enter Name:")
        self.weapon = self.get_weapon()

        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
```

Please Help!!! I am a rookie and learning.
Thank You!!

Comment: always put text instead of screenshot - we can't copy text from screenshot.

Comment: maybe your moster doesn't have attack, or it doesn't use `Combat`, or you import different file with the same name, or `Moster` import different file `combact.py` than you expect.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `help(Monsters)`?

Comment: Can you also provide the file hierarchy of your project?

Comment: Thank you, everyone I jus cleared out the cache and recompiled it. It worked perfect .there might be a problem on my machine.